# How can power factor be improved by using a capacitor in an LCR circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, power

First of all what is even meant by improving power factor? My book says we can improve power factor by making impedance tend to resistance I.e. Z-》R, and then they say that power factor is improved by nuetralizing wattless current by connecting an appropriate capacitor in parallel.  I don't understand anything.

Comment: The current and voltage of resistive elements are in phase, i.e. the product  integrated over an entire cycle is a positive number. The current and voltage of a capacitor and inductor are 90 degrees out of phase and the product integrated over an entire cycle is zero. Inductive and capacitive components that are in parallel or in series with resistive components increase peak current over the equivalent resistive components alone, but they don't consume any power (they don't get hot). By compensating for their current component we can reduce peak current and that improves the power factor.

Comment: This is pretty standard ac circuit analysis. If the voltage is 90 degrees out of phase with the current, than no power gets transferred.

Comment: What is meant by improving power factor?

Answer (score 0):

Power factor means ratio of power consumed by LCR circuit to power consumed by resistive circuit.
If Power factor is 0, it means No power is consumed by LCR circuit, although power supply is given.It acts like open circuit. When power factor is 1, it means all power supplied by source is being consumed. This is called resonance condition.

Power factor $$cosN =\frac{√R^2 +(X_{L}- X_{C})^2}{R}$$

Improving power factor means decreasing impedance of circuit, so that current easily pass through circuit.

When
$$(X_{L}- X_{C})^2$$ is minimum impedance of circuit is minimum.
When $$(X_{L}- X_{C})^2$$ is 0, impedance of circuit is R.

Comment: What is meant by improving power factor